# Importing email data based on date and time

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm trying to import data from my Outlook inbox given a specified date and time.

My problem is the macro pulls data from the first email it sees multiple times.

It does just fine with subsequent emails. How do I pull data from each email only once?

The code is basically a template I found online.

I tried getting the loop to check for duplicates and clear the contents if a duplicate was found but I got type mismatch errors.

```vb
Dim OUTAPPLICATION As Outlook.Application
Dim OUTNAMESPACE As Namespace
Dim Folder As MAPIFolder
Dim OutlookMail As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim Time As Date

Set OUTAPPLICATION = New Outlook.Application
Set OUTNAMESPACE = OUTAPPLICATION.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Folder = OUTNAMESPACE.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

i = 1

For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items
    If OutlookMail.ReceivedTime >= range("Date").Value Then
        range("Footprints").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Subject
        range("Type").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.SenderName
        range("ETA").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.ReceivedTime
        range("SH").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Body
        range("Status").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.CC
    
        i = i + 1
    
    End If
Next OutlookMail
```

The program takes a long time to run. Is there a way to get it to run faster?

Comment: I ran your code, and it seemed to work just fine, no duplicates.

Comment: To improve efficiency, try using the Restrict method to filter your items, described here `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.restrict`.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code before ending the code

```
Set Folder = Nothing
Set OUTNAMESPACE = Nothing
Set  OUTAPPLICATION= Nothing
```